# Quantifying the reduction in a thyristor's turn-off time in response to increasing reverse voltage: Seeking data or graphs

Tags: thyristor, scr, hvdc, commutation

From a previous question of mine (here: [What factors affect a thyristor's "circuit commutated turn-off time"?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/440219/what-factors-affect-a-thyristors-circuit-commutated-turn-off-time)), which was asked about 5 years ago, a user presented this very helpful guide from GE's SCR manual that qualitatively describes how varying a thyristor's turn-off parameters, such as its pre-turn-off current magnitude, the \$\frac{\text{d}i}{\text{d}t}\$, and its reverse voltage all will affect the turn-off time, \$T_\text{q}\$. The picture the user presented from the textbook is found below.

[image]

However, a follow-up question that I never seemed to ask is as follows:

**To what extent does a thyristor's turn-off time, \$T_\text{q}\$, reduce with an increasing reverse voltage during turn-off?**

My hunch is that the graph of \$T_\text{q}\$ vs. \$V_r\$ would appear logarithmic. That is, from \$V_r = 0\$ to \$V_r = V_{r0}\$ (where \$ V_{r0}\$ is the tested reverse voltage given in a datasheet, for example), there would be a steep decrease in \$T_\text{q}\$ until it levels off/plateaus, such that increasing \$V_r\$ results in only a minimal decrease in \$T_\text{q}\$.

My problem is that I cannot seem to find anywhere any sort of graph relating these two quantities.

Thanks for the read!

Comment: The higher the potential reverse voltage, the more likelihood that turning the device off will not be successful due to high dv/dt and that it will trigger again.

Comment: For this thyristor, as an example, it can handle dv/dt = 2000 V/us, while the turn-off time was tested at 20 V/us. Please assume that we are free to choose the maximum dv/dt that does not cause retriggering. Thank you! https://publisher.hitachienergy.com/preview?DocumentID=5SYA1079&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=&Action=Launch